# Error calling function in T4 template

Tags: c#, .net, t4

I have the following T4 template:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>



using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace GREDOS.Deployment.Resources
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public static readonly Version SupportedDatabaseVersion = new Version("<#= GetMaxVersionInResources(); #>");
    }
}

<#+
public static class Helper
    {
        public static string GetMaxVersionInResources()
        {
            var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var folderName = $"{executingAssembly.GetName().Name}.Sql";
            var versions = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
                .Where(f => f.StartsWith(folderName))
                .Select(f => new Version(f.Substring(f.IndexOf("__", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 2,
                        f.LastIndexOf("__", StringComparison.Ordinal) - f.IndexOf("__", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    .Replace("_", string.Empty)))
                .Distinct();
            return versions.Max(v => v).ToString();
        }
    }
#>
```

When I save, I got the following errors:

> Error CS0116  A namespace does not directly contain members such as fields or methods.    GREDOS.Deployment.Resources C:\GREDOS\Main\GREDOS.Deployment\GREDOS.Deployment.Resources\SqlVersionFinder.cs    1
>
> Error CS0103  Name 'ErrorGeneratingOutput' does not exist in the current context. GREDOS.Deployment.Resources C:\GREDOS\Main\GREDOS.Deployment\GREDOS.Deployment.Resources\SqlVersionFinder.cs
>
> Error     Compiling transform: Name 'GetMaxVersionInResources' does not exist in the current context GREDOS.Deployment.Resources  C:\GREDOS\Main\GREDOS.Deployment\GREDOS.Deployment.Resources\SqlVersionFinder.tt
>
> Error     Compiling transform: Expected ) GREDOS.Deployment.Resources C:\GREDOS\Main\GREDOS.Deployment\GREDOS.Deployment.Resources\SqlVersionFinder.tt
>
> Error     Compiling transform: Expected } GREDOS.Deployment.Resources C:\GREDOS\Main\GREDOS.Deployment\GREDOS.Deployment.Resources\SqlVersionFinder.tt

if I remove the call to the method in `<#= GetMaxVersionInResources(); #>` everything works fine.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it like this:

`Helper.GetMaxVersionInResources();`

Comment: I had already found myself the reason, it's an static method. Thanks for your time.